# How to perform language transformation(Localization ) in UITable View Content in swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

i Need to convert my iOS app into arabic .i am done with converting UIComponents text but when it comes to UItabelview,i am not able to do .i am not getting how to convert text which is in an array in swift 3

Comment: Where does the text come from?

Comment: array is static or coming from API?

Comment: array is coming from api

Answer (score 0):

You must localize your app to support different languages. 
Please refer to this [Medium Tutorial](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881) to get a clear idea on how to localize an app.

Comment: thank you but i am talking about table view not specific component

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of display strings that come from an API then you have a problem. If those strings are static and come from a known set of strings then you could create entries in your localizable.strings file that map each of those strings to their Arabic equivalent, and use NSLocalizedString() to convert them at runtime:

```
let sourceString = cellData[indexPath.row].titleString
let localizedString = NSLocalizedString(sourceString, comment: "String from API")
```

Comment: bro i am doing the same thing but nothing is happening. response is key("xyz") not found in xyz.string

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Edit your question to show the code you're trying, along with a copy-paste of the full error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your backend developer to add arabic string in response and then use below code:

```
cell.yourLabel = NSLocalizedString(YourArray[indexPath.row].arabicString, comment: "")
```

Comment: Value of type 'String' has no member 'arabicString'

Comment: are you getting arabic string in response?

Comment: First you need an arabic string in response then use above code to localize.